# findElements in RemoteWebDriver on Safari MacOS throws exception

Tags: macos, selenium, safari, remotewebdriver, safaridriver

I know that the method findElements should return list of elements every time.
even if no elements found the list will be empty.
I have strange behavior of this function when I use RemoteWebDriver on MAC OS SIERRA with safari driver.
When the elements not found I get a NoSuchElementException 
(An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.)

Is this the correct behavior with remoteWebDriver?

Hezi

Comment: Are you using RemoteWebDriver explicitly? If yes, why?

Comment: How else? This is the only way that works for me

Comment: Always use WebDriver interface and selenium will know if you need WebDriver or its specific implementation RemoteWebDriver

Comment: The remotewebdriver impliment the webdriver interface and it is exist to work on remote computer!!

Comment: To run tests remotely you should use selenium grid and you normally use WebDriver interface, there is no need to use Remote classes explicitly, it's just a bad practice. Sorry I couldn't answer your question, but you could consider these advices.

Comment: As far as I know the only way to use selenium grid is with remotewebdriver. please correct me if I am wrong. If not give an example for what you are saying

Comment: Ok, I think that we didn't understand ourselves correctly, I misunderstood you completely. Back on topic, is this 'issue' present when you use some other driver remotely (other than safari).

Comment: I didn't try but I create renmotedriver and give capabilities of safari. The method impliment on the remote driver

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue, @HeziIsraeli , Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No. I don't work with it anymore but you can override this function